# Requesting list of Companies from Swagger UI

Tags: api, request, swagger

I have embarked on a new project in which I am trying to source data from a REST API. The documentation to this API is available here: https://www.zefixintg.admin.ch/ZefixPublicREST/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/ZefixPublicREST/v3/api-docs/swagger-config#/.

I am specifically interested in the following: /api/v1/company/search.

Unfortunately, I am unable to receive a 200 response with my following query. Instead it always results in an authorisation error 401:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

params= {"activeOnly": TRUE}

response = requests.get(url='https://www.zefixintg.admin.ch/ZefixPublicREST/api/v1/company/search',
                        auth= HTTPBasicAuth('<user>', '<password>'),
                        params=params)

print(response.status_code)
```

I am not sure what other way I should be authorising myself as I have been told that I would only need a user and a password, which the API owner has provided to me. Am I using an incorrect method for this use case?

Thanks for the support!

Fred

Comment: You should be using a POST request (`requests.post(...)`), not GET.

Comment: even if i change my requests method to .post i receive the same issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my own issue, which consisted of putting the authentication into the header, encoding the user and password and re-labeling my param's to payload's:

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://www.zefixintg.admin.ch/ZefixPublicREST/api/v1/company/search"

payload = json.dumps({
  "activeOnly": True,
  "legalSeatId": 460
})
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Basic <user/password>'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Please note that I didn't include the encoded user/password in the query. To find the solution it definitely helped me to use [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) to test my api request.